Focus out SyncFusoins document editor in Angular
Hi there I have a problem using SyncFusions document editor with Angular.
I have put down the editor in my HTML template as such
  <ejs-documenteditorcontainer
    height="100vh"
    serviceUrl="https://services.syncfusion.com/angular/production/api/documenteditor/"
    #documentEditor
    id="documentEditor"
    (contentChange)="onContentChange()"
    class="editor-container"
  />

Inside my TS I get a reference to the editor container like such
 @ViewChild('documentEditor')
  editorContainer!: DocumentEditorContainerComponent;

Now, the editor can be focused on by clicking anywhere inside the white space of the editor, and focused out (the caret disappears for example) when clicking anywhere outside the editor space.
What I need is to programmatically focus out the from the editor.
I have noticed that there are loads of function, some not even documented anywhere inside the documentation that might help me.
I have tried some function, but there are to many to try find a specific one.
I have trued function that append to
  this.editorContainer.FUNCS()
  this.editorContainer.documentEditor.FUNCS()
  this.editorContainer.documentEditor.selections.FUNCS()
  this.editorContainer.documentEditor.editor.FUNCS()


Currently, Document editor does not have support to perform focus-out operations from the document editor. We have logged this as feature request. We don’t have any immediate plans to implement this feature now.
You can track the status of feature from the below link:
https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/60180/provide-support-to-perform-focus-out-operation-from-document-editor
